# How to replace a argument that contains path-value in properties file?

Tags: xml, shell

I am new to shell scripting. I have a folder named **myfolder** that contains some xml files. I also have a properties file as mentioned below:

```
user=admin
password=admin

# location of xml test file
inputPath=/home/filename.xml
#reporter=XMLReporter
outputPath=/home/filename.csv
numThreads=5
reportTime=true
reportResults=true
```

I want to replace both **inputPath** & **outputPath** values with list of file names(nearly 10 filenames) that I have taken from the folder **myfolder**. In my code I tried to replace inputPath alone first as follows:

```
for i in `ls myfolder/*.xml`; do 
sed -i 's/inputPath=*/inputPath=/home/$i/g' propertiesfile
done
```

But I get an error like *: command not found 
sed: -e expression #1, char 29: unknown option to `s'*

I have replaced `/` with `|` even though got the same error. How can I do this with a for loop till all the filenames to be replaced?? Can anyone help on this??

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You need to use a different regex delimiter other than `/` since your matching pattern also has `/`
2. You need to use double quotes for shell variable expansion
3. You should not parse `ls` command's output and rely on shell globing.

Try this sed command:

```
for i in myfolder/*.xml; do 
    sed -i.bak "s#^\(inputPath=\).*$#$1/home/$i#" propertiesfile
done
```

Comment: Thanks this script may help